# Perl divide hash into equal parts based on count and send for Parallel execution

Tags: perl, hash, parallel-processing, fork

I have a hash(`%hash`) which contains list of nodes and the commands which needs to be executed for respective nodes.

Before to that I have list of hosts(`@alive_hosts`) to in which host it should execute.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @alive_hosts = qw/10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2/;
print Dumper(\@alive_hosts);

my %hash = (
          'Node1' => 'cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3',
          'Node2' => 'cmd2 | cmd3',
          'Node3' => 'cmd4 | cmd1',
          'Node4' => 'cmd1',
          'Node5' => 'cmd2',
          'Node6' => 'cmd1 | cmd2',
          'Node7' => 'cmd3 | cmd4',
);
print Dumper(\%hash);

my $num_buckets = scalar @alive_hosts;
print "num_buckets:$num_buckets\n"; 

my $no_of_nodes = scalar keys %hash;

my $per_bucket  = int( $no_of_nodes / $num_buckets ); 
print "per_bucket:$per_bucket\n";

my $num_extras  =      $no_of_nodes % $num_buckets; 
print "num_extras:$num_extras\n";
```

I want to divide this hash(`%hash`) in such a way that, based in number of alive hosts hash should be divided. So that it will be distributed to each of the hosts.
In above example,
Host1(`10.0.0.1`) should contain:

```
'Node1' => 'cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3',
'Node2' => 'cmd2 | cmd3',
'Node3' => 'cmd4 | cmd1',
'Node4' => 'cmd1'
```

Host2(`10.0.0.2`) should contain:

```
'Node5' => 'cmd2',
'Node6' => 'cmd1 | cmd2',
'Node7' => 'cmd3 | cmd4'
```

These above 2 values can be kept in new hash and from there I need to execute a shell script passing the above values (i.e., Node & cmds) as an parameter in parallel. To execute this in parallely I was thinking to use `Parallel::Loops` or `Parallel::ForkManager`. Any idea/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've worked out how many nodes you need in each of your new hashes. So you can get a list of the keys from the big hash and just `slice()` that number off each time round a loop.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.20; # For the new hash slices
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @alive_hosts = qw/10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2/;
print Dumper(\@alive_hosts);

my %hash = (
          'Node1' => 'cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3',
          'Node2' => 'cmd2 | cmd3',
          'Node3' => 'cmd4 | cmd1',
          'Node4' => 'cmd1',
          'Node5' => 'cmd2',
          'Node6' => 'cmd1 | cmd2',
          'Node7' => 'cmd3 | cmd4',
);
print Dumper(\%hash);

my $no_of_nodes = scalar keys %hash;
my $num_buckets = scalar @alive_hosts;

my $per_bucket  = int( $no_of_nodes / $num_buckets );
$per_bucket++ if $no_of_nodes % $num_buckets;

my @keys = keys %hash;

my %node_hash;

for (1 .. $num_buckets) {
  my @newkeys = splice @keys, 0, $per_bucket;

  $node_hash{$alive_hosts[$_ - 1]} = { %hash{@newkeys} }; # New hash slice syntax
}

say Dumper \%node_hash;
```

**Note:** I use the new(ish) (since Perl 5.20) `%hash{...}` hash slice syntax. If you're using an earlier version of Perl, you'll need to adjust that line.

Comment: Thanks @dave. This solves the problem of creation of new hash. I have updated the question how I can have this value to be executed in Parallel processing.

Comment: @vinodk89: If you have a further question, then please don't just add it on here - post a new question on the site.

Answer (score -1):

See if you find next approach acceptable

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @alive_hosts = qw/10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2/;
print Dumper(\@alive_hosts);

my %hash = (
          'Node1' => 'cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3',
          'Node2' => 'cmd2 | cmd3',
          'Node3' => 'cmd4 | cmd1',
          'Node4' => 'cmd1',
          'Node5' => 'cmd2',
          'Node6' => 'cmd1 | cmd2',
          'Node7' => 'cmd3 | cmd4',
);
print Dumper(\%hash);

my %dispatch;
my @hosts;

while( my($node,$cmd) = each %hash ) {
    @hosts = @alive_hosts unless @hosts;
    my $host = shift @hosts;
    $dispatch{$host}{$node} = $cmd;

}

say Dumper(\%dispatch);
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          '10.0.0.1',
          '10.0.0.2'
        ];
$VAR1 = {
          'Node1' => 'cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3',
          'Node4' => 'cmd1',
          'Node6' => 'cmd1 | cmd2',
          'Node5' => 'cmd2',
          'Node3' => 'cmd4 | cmd1',
          'Node7' => 'cmd3 | cmd4',
          'Node2' => 'cmd2 | cmd3'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '10.0.0.1' => {
                          'Node6' => 'cmd1 | cmd2',
                          'Node1' => 'cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3',
                          'Node3' => 'cmd4 | cmd1',
                          'Node2' => 'cmd2 | cmd3'
                        },
          '10.0.0.2' => {
                          'Node4' => 'cmd1',
                          'Node5' => 'cmd2',
                          'Node7' => 'cmd3 | cmd4'
                        }
        };
```